# Portfolio optimization on R with constraints

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, finance, portfolio

I'm trying to solve this problem where I've to find the minimum variance portfolio composed on the asset in the Dataset, given that each weight should be larger than 0 and the sum equal to 1. Using this code I get a weights vector which respect only the second constraint (sum=1) while in the solution I get negative results. How can I fix it?

```
Dataset<- as.matrix(Dataset) 
nAss<- dim(Dataset)
nAss<- nAss[2]

diagmat<- diag(1, nrow=nAss, ncol=nAss)
onevec<- rep(1, nAss)
onevec<- t(onevec)
Amatint<- rbind(onevec, diagmat)
Amat<- t(Amatint)

bvec<- c(1, rep(0, 15))
dvec<- rep(0, nAss)
res<- solve.QP(cov(Dataset), dvec=dvec, Amat=Amat, bvec=bvec, meq = 1)
```

thanks :)

Comment: Should `bvec<- c(1, rep(0, 15))` not use `nAss`? Otherwise make sure we can reproduce the problem.